# R does not update data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here is my current version of `data.table`:

```
      Package                                                        LibPath Version Priority       Depends
1: data.table /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library   1.9.2       NA R (>= 2.14.0)
             Imports LinkingTo
1: methods, reshape2        NA
                                                                                            Suggests Enhances    License
1: chron, ggplot2 (>= 0.9.0), plyr, reshape, testthat (>= 0.4),\nhexbin, fastmatch, nlme, xts, bit64       NA GPL (>= 2)
   License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built Status
1:              NA                    NA      NA     NA              yes 3.1.0     ok
```

As you can see, its `1.9.2`, despite http://cran.us.r-project.org listing `1.9.4` as current. I tried the following to update it, but with little effect:

```
update.packages()
update.packages(repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
update.packages(old.packages='data.table', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

`sessionInfo()` still gives me

```
other attached packages:
[1] foreign_0.8-61   data.table_1.9.2 ggplot2_1.0.0
```

I'm on Mac OS X, and the current version of R. Detaching the package prior to updating does not help.

Comment: any warning messages?  have you tried other mirrors?

Comment: Nothing comes up by default (is there a way to force more output?). I tried two other mirrors, Austrian and Australian.

Comment: how about simply running `install.packages("data.table")` (unless you want to understand *why* this is happening, and not just work around it)?  Are you sure that detaching was completely effective (maybe you need `unload=TRUE`)?  What happens if you start from a clean R session?

Comment: Just did the install. Here is some info: 'There is a binary version available (and will be installed) but the source version is later            binary source
data.table  1.9.2  1.9.4'

Comment: OK, then try `install.packages("data.table",type="source")` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Snow Leopard binaries are not being rebuilt: going to http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html shows that 1.9.4 is available for all other platforms (source, Windows, OS X Mavericks), but only 1.9.2 is available for Snow Leopard.

I don't know whether this is something transient/known/worth reporting to CRAN maintainers or not.  (Perhaps report it to the package maintainer, who will probably (a) want to know if he doesn't already and (b) report it to the CRAN maintainers if it's not an already-known issue.)

I guess the more general debugging advice is to check the CRAN info page for the package, and the actual URLs for the package type you're interested in (in this case http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/contrib/3.1/ **or** http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/ ), directly.

A workaround is to use

```
install.packages("data.table",type="source")
```

(provided you have development tools installed).

Comment: I'm actually on Mavericks (10.9.5): Software  OS X 10.9.5 (13F34). Other than that, spot on.

Comment: It seems that this keeps being an issue. I tried to update it now to '1.9.5', but neither `update.packages()`, nor `update.packages('data.table, type='source')` give me any output.